# A wrong about SubTree

Tags: python, tree

**This is the question:** You have two every large binary trees: T1, with millions of nodes, and T2, with hundreds of nodes. Create an algorithm to decide if T2 is a subtree of T1.And my code is as the follow:

class TreeNode:

```
def __init__(self, val):
    self.val = val
    self.left, self.right = None, None
```

class Solution:

```
# @param T1, T2: The roots of binary tree.
# @return: True if T2 is a subtree of T1, or false.

def isSubtree(self, T1, T2):
    if self.tree_match(T1, T2):
        return True
    if T1 is None:
        return False
    return self.isSubtree(T1.left, T2) or self.tree_match(T1.right, T2) 

def tree_match(self, t1, t2):
    if t1 is None and t2 is None:
        return True
    if None in [t1, t2] or t1.val != t2.val:
        return False
    return self.tree_match(t1.left, t2.left) and self.tree_match(t1.right, t2.right)
```

But when input these:
{1,#,2,#,3,#,4,#,5,#,6,#,7,#,8,#,9,#,10}, {4,#,5,#,6,#,7,#,8,#,9,#,10}
**it output False,but it expects true** 。I look the code but i can't find where is wrong,so can help me ?Thank you!

Comment: `self.isSubtree(T1.left, T2) or self.tree_match(T1.right, T2)` -> shouldn't that be `isSubtree()` for both sides? Otherwise it's only a subtree when the right subtree is equal.

Comment: How do your inputs represent binary trees?

Comment: I would second dhke.

Comment: Ok,Thank you very much!You are right,i just care about my solution but don't find mistyping the code!